# C++ 2010 и библиотека msvcr100.dll

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c++

Пытаюсь перенести откомпилированное приложение на другой комп, требует библиотеку msvcr100.dll, почему? Ведь я использую WINAPI. Как сделать свой проект без этой библиотеки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, можно оную библиотеку прицепить к программе статично и она требоваться не будет.

Делается это так: в свойствах проекта идёте на пункт C/C++, а далее на Code Generation.
Там есть свойство Runtime Library. Выберите ту, где нет надписи DLL. Отладочную (Debug) или нет версию - это зависит от конфигурации проекта.
[image: пример]

Есть возможность использовать совсем другую стандартную библиотеку, но это сложнее и менее удобно =)

Comment: А для чего это библиотека вообще нужна, не достаточно WINAPI!? Помойму в VC++ 6.0 Такого счастья небыло!? :) Бесит, то что к своему конкретному коду добавляется еще всякая байда! Я бы понял если бы это был VB...

Comment: Было, просто она входила в состав ОС сразу =)
В ней CRT сидит да ещё всякое нужное... Стандартные функции С - работа со строками, файлами, памятью и всё остальное хорошее. Там очень много чего - так и не перечислить. В MSDN есть поподробнее, что туда напихали =)

Comment: А вчём разница ключей /MT и /MTd ?

Comment: В том, что в Debug-версии есть отладочная информация, проверки всякие дополнительные и всё такое, что необходимо на этапе разработки программы.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, можно скопировать библиотеку в то же место, где находится исполняемый файл. Во-вторых, компилируйте проект не в отладочной версии (Debug), а в выпускной (Release), она библиотек не требует, т.к. библиотечный код включен в другие файлы проекта (правда, их расширения не помню).

Answer (score 0):

Ну и, наконец, можно отказаться от стандартной библиотеки опцией, скриншот которой привели выше. Там есть вариант «без библиотеки».

Если после этого будут ошибки линковки — не обессудьте, значит вы её всё же используете!

Comment: После этого ошибки наверняка будут, поскольку в отладочном режиме компилятор часто генерирует код, в котором используются функции этой библиотеки. Если Вы, конечно, не используете проэкт Win32.

Comment: В чём нет ничего необычного.

Answer (score 0):

Msvcr*.dll - это библиотеки, поставляемые с С++ компилятором. Они содержат, например, функции выделения/освобождения памяти, которые работают поверх WinAPI. Т.е. используется, скажем, функция WinAPI для выделения страниц виртуальной памяти процессу, а на полученных страницах функции malloc/free из msvcr создают кучу и выделяет из неё маленькие кусочки.

Статичная линковка это, конечно, хорошо, но иногда создаёт другие проблемы. Например, если exe и используемая им dll оба слинкованы с msvcr статично, нельзя в exe выделить кусок памяти, а в dll его освободить. Чтобы обойтись без статичной линковки надо ставить Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package. Например, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555